# How do you link a Git Repo to an Existing Git Repo in a project using Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have 2 projects which i have cloned one in "ConnectData" folder and one in "MinimalAPI" folder i started the "MinimalAPI" project and everything works fine, git links the files and i have that lock icon next to each file. But when i want to reference another project which is cloned such as the "ConnectData" project inside the "MinimalAPI" project, the "ConnectData" project does not seem to be linked to git as the lock icon isn't there, this will explain further in the i[image]mage below:
As you can see the Connect.Data project isnt linked to git but minimalapi is so how do i link connect.data to git within this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is currently testing this feature, and it is still in preview. If you want to enable it you've to go to your options and then 'Preview Features'. You can find the following setting:

[image]

If you enable that, then it should work.

You can read more about it [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repo-support-in-visual-studio/) in one of their blogs. Make sure you've at least Visual Studio 2022.